# Auditing a table with many columns without Fine Grained Auditing

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have to create a trigger for a table with many columns and I want to now if is any possibility to avoid using the name of the column after :new and :old. Instead of specifically use the column name I want to use the element from collection with column names of target table (the table on which the trigger is set).

The line 25 is that with the binding error:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Updating customer id'||col_name(i)||to_char(:new.col_name(i)));
```

Bellow you can see my trigger:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_TRG BEFORE
      INSERT OR
      UPDATE ON ITEMS REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW FOR EACH ROW DECLARE TYPE col_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(60);
      col_name col_list := col_list();
      total   INTEGER;
      counter INTEGER :=0;
      BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        INTO total
        FROM user_tab_columns
        WHERE table_name = 'ITEMS';
        FOR rec IN
        (SELECT column_name FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'ITEMS'
        )
        LOOP
          col_name.extend;
          counter          :=counter+1;
          col_name(counter) := rec.column_name;
          dbms_output.put_line(col_name(counter));
        END LOOP;
        dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(total));
        FOR i IN 1 .. col_name.count
        LOOP
        IF UPDATING(col_name(i)) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Updating customer id'||col_name(i)||to_char(:new.col_name(i)));
        END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
```

Sincerely,

Comment: No, it's not.  Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you could potentially write some code that dynamically builds the trigger you want based on the data dictionary.

Comment: I want to use the trigger for crating an audit table with records for every column changed.

Comment: Can you send me a link with an example, pls.

Comment: One example https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must refine my previous answer based on what has been said by [Justin Cave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave) and also my findings. We can create a dynamic list of values triggered by INSERTING and UPDATING, based on referencing clause (old and new). For example I have created 2 collections of type nested table with varchars. One collection will contain all column tabs, as strings, that I will use for auditing and another collection will contains values for that columns with binding reference (ex. :new.). After INSERTING predicate I have created a index by collection (an associative array) of strings with ID taken from list of strings with column tab name and the value taken from the list of values for that columns referenced by new. Due to the index by collection you have a full working dynamic list at your disposal. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

After digging more I have found that is not possible to dynamically reference the :new.column_name or :old.column_name values in a trigger. Due to this I will use my code only to INSERT (it does not have an old value :-() and I will do some code in java to generate UPDATE statements.